# How do I use placement new here?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

I have a region of memory, which will be used for multiple queues. For example, I allocate 1024 bytes of memory and I need two queues. The first queue will occupy the first 512 bytes and the second the next 512 bytes.

However, my queue is represented by a C++ class. Using the placement new operator, how can I construct each queue object. Is the following approach correct?

```
Queue *q1, *q2;
void *mem = malloc( 1024 );

*q1 = new (mem) Queue;
*q2 = new (mem+512)Queue;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
Queue* mem = static_cast<Queue*>(malloc(2 * sizeof(Queue));
Queue* q1 = new (mem) Queue;
Queue* q2 = new (mem+1) Queue;
```

If it's important that the two queues are exactly 512 bytes from each other your original suggestion is almost correct:

```
char* mem = static_cast<char*>(malloc(1024));
Queue* q1 = new (mem) Queue;
Queue* q2 = new (mem+512) Queue;
```

This assumes `sizeof(Queue) <= 512`. The reason for the cast to `char*` is that pointer arithmetic with `void*` is illegal in C++.

Comment: +1, just to outline the difference - you can't increment `void*` pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Unless sizeof( Queue ) == 512, which it probably isn't unless you have a very specialized implementation, then your approach won't work. You need to make sure that the actual nodes instead are allocated on the memory slice you've been given by malloc. As for using placement new, not withholding potential issues with memory alignment:

```
 char* mem = static_cast< char* >( malloc( 1024 ) );
 Queue* q1 = new ( mem ) Queue;
 Queue* q1 = new ( mem + 512 ) Queue;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks very strange to me. I do not see a reason why to do it this way.
You need to save "mem" for free

When I want two Queue at once, I would do it this way

```
class DoubleQueue {
   public Queue q1;
   public Queue q2;
}

...
DoubleQueue dq = new DoubleQueue;
```

Or

```
Queue queue [] = new Queue [2];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you have the pointer dereferences for uninitialized pointers on the lhs of both assigning operators, so, you try to assign the addresses to the values.

To me this code implies that the Queue class resides on top of the data chunk, not knowing anything about it (you do not have Ctor arguments, indicating the memory chunk size). Maybe it's more convenient to give the Queue object a pointer to the memory chunk and a chunk size to it's Ctor?